# PostgreSQL server doesn't release memory until connection from PHP/Laravel client is closed

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, memory, postgis

I have a daemon written in PHP/Laravel that connects to a PostgreSQL database using PDO and executes jobs from a queue. A job typically takes 30 minutes to run. It consists of several PostgreSQL queries with PostGIS.

With every SQL query server memory usage increases. The memory is freed only when the connection is closed. So if I run several jobs consecutively the server eventually runs out of memory.

I have been able to temporarily solve the problem by having my daemon periodically reconnect to the database. **However, why does the memory not get released unless I disconnect from the server?**

---

Some details about the environment:

In queries I use PostGIS functions `ST_Contains()`, `ST_GeomFromText()`, `ST_Area()` for SELECTs and other simple plain SQL SELECTs with similar UPDATE.

Example of query:

```sql
select id
from gtn
where ST_Contains(geo_polygon::geometry, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0.000000 0.000000)', 4326))
order by ST_Area(geo_polygon::geometry) asc;
```

All PostgreSQL settings are default, except one:

```
effective_cache_size = 1GB
```

Tuning the settings using [this tool](https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua) did not help:

```
# DB Version: 12
# OS Type: linux
# DB Type: web
# Total Memory (RAM): 4 GB
# CPUs num: 2
# Data Storage: ssd

max_connections = 200
shared_buffers = 1GB
effective_cache_size = 3GB
maintenance_work_mem = 256MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 2621kB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 4GB
```

- Connection to PostgreSQL using PHP PDO;
- Laravel: v5.7.29;
- PHP:

```
PHP 7.4.33 (cli) (built: Nov 15 2022 06:05:55) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.33, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.8, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

- Docker image: postgres:12;
- PostgreSQL:

```
# psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.13 (Debian 12.13-1.pgdg100+1)
```

- PostGIS:

```
# psql -U postgres -c 'SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version();'
                                                                                          postgis_full_version          
                                                                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POSTGIS="3.3.2 4975da8" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771" PROJ="Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 201
8" LIBXML="2.9.4" LIBJSON="0.12.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.1" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"
(1 row)
```

Also, I found [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20191218145521.oyhvjn5ptf3a6ej4%40development#bedfd6b0c6e68d9550d9a80a1a6ecfb5), but there has not any solution.

**UPD: 2023-02-18**

As said jjanes, I've executed the follow query 100 times using PHP PDO (without Laravel at all) and psql CLI:

```sql
select id
from gtn
where "view" is not null
    and geo_polygon is not null
    and ST_Contains(geo_polygon::geometry, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0.000000 0.000000)', 4326))
order by ST_Area(geo_polygon::geometry) asc
limit 2;
```

After this, memory of postgres process was increased by 50 Mb, both PHP PDO and psql CLI. Only after disconnect from the DB the memory got released.

Then I've run the simple query 100 times:

```sql
select id from gtn limit 100;
```

when my memory has been increased only by 1 Mb and didn't increase during execution anymore. The memory got released only after disconnect too.

Using PHP PDO I tried to run `gdb`. I added to `dockere-compose.yml` service of postgres the following config:

```
cap_add:
   - SYS_PTRACE
security_opt:
   - seccomp:unconfined
```

and installed `postgresql-12-dbgsym postgresql-12-postgis-3-dbgsym gcc gdb libc6-dbg libffi6-dbg libgcc1-dbg libkrb5-dbg libstdc++6-8-dbg libxml2-dbg zlib1g-dbg libkrb5-dbg` packages.

I run my query again using PHP PDO and after executed query 100 times, `gdb` showed me next:

```
$ gdb -p 70

...

(No debugging symbols found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd.so.0)
Cannot access memory at address 0x7f5264494088

warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
Failed to read a valid object file image from memory.
Unable to read JIT descriptor from remote memory
0x00007f526367ad16 in epoll_wait (epfd=3, events=0x55f87ab9cfb8, maxevents=1, timeout=-1)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/epoll_wait.c:30
30  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/epoll_wait.c: No such file or directory.
```

I could not even execute `p MemoryContextStats(TopMemoryContext)` for `gdb`, because I get a `Couldn't get extended state status: No such process.` error.

Comment: Two important questions; 1. "Memory of PostgreSQL" - is this the backend process of your connection, a different backend process or the total for all PostgreSQL processes? 2. Are these queries being run in a single transaction?

Comment: 1. Backend process of my connection.
2. No transactions at all.

Comment: I would expect subsequent queries on the same connection to reuse the existing memory allocation. Also anything expected to be much larger than the `work_mem` setting gets spilled to disk. You are probably going to have to track the memory usage after each query and see whether one in particular is causing the problem.

Comment: Do you mean memory leak? For this job I use only one connection to DB. Memory is released when I disconnect client of DB. In PHP is used PDO interface to connect to DB. I have made workaround doing reconnect client every 10k queries. And it's solved my problem for now.

Comment: Can you do this to find out which context the memory is being used in? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ#Examining_backend_memory_use

Comment: Can you just run your example query over and over and see if it leaks?  Then do it from psql rather than php and see if that leaks?

Comment: jjanes, I'v added some new information for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a few answers at SO ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62679906/5923509), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61348800/5923509) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3849760/5923509)), I have found the solution for me. I just have made `postgresql.conf` more polite for my local development:

```
max_connections = 30
shared_buffers = 128MB
effective_cache_size = 384MB
maintenance_work_mem = 32MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 3932kB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 1456kB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 4GB
max_worker_processes = 6
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 3
max_parallel_workers = 6
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 3
```

I suppose the resources distribute for each connection individually and multiply at `max_connection` if it's necessary. My last configuration, where `max_connections = 100`, was too big. Once I have changed configuration as above I have seen not more 1 Gb for long repeatedly requests and OOM doesn't occur anymore.

Therefore, I think that my problem was in misconfiguration, not in memory leak.